# multiple keys in a MapReduce Job

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'am hadoop newbie. I'm trying to run MapReduce (programming in Java), where the key is multiple keys ( Text). which type of array should i use to store those keys to pass them then as parameter to the outputCollector? thanks!!!

Comment: if the list isn't complex then you can have the keys in a single comma separated string and set that to the Text object being passed to outputCollector. And in reducer split out the key to get the list of multiple keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write your own class that `implements WritableComparable<YourClassName>` to store the keys together in a concise object. See [this link](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/databases/hadoop/9780596521974/serialization/id3548156) for a good example.

Comment: Yes that's what i did =)) Thank youuu!

Answer (score 0):

if it just some Text values, i would suggest to just send them as a delimited String. it is convenient and straight forward. otherwise you could do as suggested by Quetzalcoatl. you might find these 2 questions useful :
[How do i set an Object as the Value for Map output in Hadoop MapReduce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13877077/how-do-i-set-an-object-as-the-value-for-map-output-in-hadoop-mapreduce/13877688#13877688)
[How (in Hadoop),is the data put into map and reduce functions in correct types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961474/how-in-hadoop-is-the-data-put-into-map-and-reduce-functions-in-correct-types/10965026#10965026)